# Make a call and keep the app in front, Android

Tags: android, call

first of all, sorry but i'm not a native english speaker.

I would like to make and app with only one button and when you press it make a call, but the call has to do it in background because I would like to keep always the screen of my app visible. How should I do it?

I tried with a phoneStateListener but I could not the expected result because sometimes the screens turns off and the app didn't restar correctly...

I will be amazing if I could make a button to finish the call in my app, but this is optionally

Thank you!

Comment: Another way it could be restart the app at the same time that I make the call, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make such "invisible" calls from your app due to the Android security policy

Comment: OK, and could I restart the app at the same time that the call starts? 

Because with the flag CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK and CALL_STATE_IDDLE I know how restart the app after the call, but I don't know how to do it at the same time that you make this call.